# How do I make a loop that will print out all of the elements in my array if the keys are strings and not ints?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print out all of the values in my array, however the keys for the elements are strings.  How do I make a loop that will print out all of the elements in my array if the keys are strings and not ints?

Here is my code so far: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xGhmhX

Comment: See the PHP docs on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.  Numeric `for` loops (C-style) are not used that often in PHP. `foreach` is far more common.  `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

Comment: This looks like homework. The PHP docs are your friends! =]

Comment: @stytown The answer I gave for your previous question had the exact solution you are looking for in this question...

Comment: @Grexis In which case, you should flag the question as a dupe. Will do the same =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [**`foreach`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct :

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
    // Work with either $key or $value
}
```

Or, if you don't need the key inside the loop, you can just use :

```
foreach ($your_array as $value) {
    // Work with $value
}
```